# MongoDB Find queries slow while updating/inserting schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm doing a big loop once a day - which updating existing documents in the database (and also inserting new documents).

this loop get executed in a separate server ( prevents from the main server to be slow ), but the main problem is that all the find queries on the Data base (while the loop is executed) are very slow (the loop slows it down significantly).

This is a very big issue in my website ( this loop must be executed once a day )  and iv'e been trying to find a solution online - but i couldn't manage to find something.
Is there any way to prevent the find queries from being so slow while inserting/updating the database??

```
    uploadProductsManually = async (name, products, map, valuesMap) => {
      return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
        const company = await Company.findOne({ name }).exec();
        if (!company) return reject(new errors.NotFound("Company not found"));

        const rows = products;
        const parsedRows = [];

        const findCorrectKey = (key) => {
          const correctKey = key.trim();
          if (productFields[correctKey]) return productFields[correctKey];

          const category = map.find((item) => {
            return item.options.some((option) => {
              return option.trim().toLowerCase() === correctKey.toLowerCase();
            });
          });
          const categoryName = category && category.name;
          return productFields[categoryName];
        };
        const hashProductValues = (product) => {
          let valueToHash;
          if (product.productId) {
            valueToHash = product.productId;
          } else if (product.certificateId) {
            valueToHash = product.certificateId;
          } else {
            valueToHash = JSON.stringify(
              product.size + product.color
            );
          }
          return base64encode(valueToHash);
        };

        rows.forEach(function (row, i) {
          var newProduct = {};
          for (var key in row) {
            var val = row[key];
            if (val) {
              let normalizedKey = findCorrectKey(key);
              if (normalizedKey) {
                newProduct[normalizedKey] = val;
              }
              let normalizedValue = normalizeValue(normalizedKey, val,valuesMap);
 newProduct[normalizedKey] = normalizedValue;
            }
          }
          newProduct.channels = [];
          if (newProduct.productId) {
            parsedRows.push(newProduct);
          }
        });

        fetchProducts();
        function fetchProducts() {
          Product.find({ company: company._id }).exec(function (err, products) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            var map = {};
            if (products) {
              products.forEach(function (product) {
                const productIdentifier = hashProductValues(product);
                map[productIdentifier] = product;
                if (product.productStatus == "manual") {
                  // product.isAvailable = false;
                  // product.save();
                } else {
                  product.status = "deleted";
                  product.save();
                }
              });
            }
            mergeData(map);
          });
        }

        async function mergeData(map) {
          let created = 0;
          let updated = 0;
          let manual = 0;
          async.each(
            parsedRows,
            function (row, callback) {
              const productIdentifier = hashProductValues(row);
              let product = map[productIdentifier];
              if (product) {
                map[productIdentifier] = undefined;
                Product.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $set: updatedProduct }, function (
                  err,
                  updatedProd
                ) {
                  if (err) {
                    // errors.push(productIdentifier);
                    console.log("err is:", err);
                  }
                  updated++;
                  callback();
                });
              } else {
                row = new Product(row);
                row.save(function (err) {
                  if (err) {
                    // errors.push(productIdentifier);
                    console.log(err);
                  }
                  created++;
                  callback();
                });
              }
            },
            (err) => {
              if (err) return reject(err);
              Company.findByIdAndUpdate(
                company._id,
                { lastUpdate: new Date() },
                function (err, comp) {
                  if (err) console.log(err);
                }
              );
              console.log(
                `Created: ${created}\nUpdated: ${updated} \manual: ${manual}`
              );
              resolve({
                created,
                updated,
                manual,
                errors,
              });
            }
          );
        }
      });
    };
```

Comment: please provide relevant code, schema and other relevant information in order to get a reasonable answer

Comment: it's not a specific thing - its very generic.
i got a lot of queries going on (also queries that are not related to the updated schema)
basically the whole search in the data base is way slower.

Comment: how do you expect to get an answer that works with so little background information?

Comment: i just added the code which gets executed in the loop  @NikosM.

Comment: But i'll say it again... i want to know if slower db is a normal thing while updating / inserting to schema, and what can i do to improve the performance

Comment: performance as you may already know depends on many factors, db choice, db type, schema architecture, underlying server, query types and so on.. So all this info is relevant there is no magic bullet that works for every case

Comment: @NikosM. of course, but i'm talking about a situation of finding while inserting.
i did not see any information about that online.

Comment: one thing you can try right now while waiting for more answers is to run a simplified versin of your script that only finds and updates single product and run it multiple times and measure performance. If it is slow then most probably it is your db server and/or schema, else it is the convoluted code and/or amount of rows updated per script call

Comment: @NikosM. 
Basically your'e saying that the DB performance should not be slower while updating/inserting?

Comment: It depends on the used schema, if the schema used is badly designed it may have issues, but it may be designed well and still have issues because of other factors